# Messenger webhook - can't verify the URL - Python

Tags: python, flask, facebook-messenger, ngrok

Can't validate the URL I have setup using ngrok. The error message is as follows:

```
Error
The URL couldn't be validated. Please try again.
```

Once I try validate in the app settings I get a 403 error in the terminal

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2019 20:26:39] "GET /webhook?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=607343413&hub.verify_token=hello HTTP/1.1" 403 -
```

My code

```
import os, sys
from flask import Flask,request
app = Flask(__name__)

VERIFY_TOKEN = "hello"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "This is a Facebook Messenger test bot server."


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET'])
def verify():
    # webhook verification
    if request.args.get('hub.mode') == 'subscribe' and request.args.get('hub.challenge'):
        if request.args.get('hub.verify_token') == VERIFY_TOKEN:
            return 'Verification token missmatch', 403
        return request.args['hub.challange'], 200
    return 'verification token', 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = False)
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed if request.args.get('hub.verify_token') == VERIFY_TOKEN: to if request.args.get('hub.verify_token') != VERIFY_TOKEN:

This is what happens now when I try to enable webhooks integration.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2019 20:45:49] "GET /webhook?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=2128593822&hub.verify_token=hello HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/app.py", line 18, in verify
    return request.args['hub.challange'], 200
  File "/users/ec4/user/super-duper-telegram/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 443, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'hub.challange'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2019 20:45:57] "GET /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Sidebar, but you can easily and programmatically manage `ngrok` from Python application using `pyngrok`. Flask example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have `return request.args['hub.challange'], 200` but in query `&hub.challenge` therefore you get KeyError, as hub.chall**e**nge != hub.chall**a**nge

Answer (score 0):

See you have that if the token matches VERIFY TOKEN (hello), it will fail, change the condition to !=